# C# VSTO Winform Control Access controls from dynamically created Form

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, excel-addins

I have an *Excel* Addin that call a Windows Form that has a List Box. Before I show the form, I want to populate the `ListBox` dynamically based on values from *Excel*.

Winform Looks like below:

[image]

Button click within Ribbon looks like below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Form1 fm = new Form1();
    System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lbx = fm.Controls.Find("listBox1", true).FirstOrDefault() as System.Windows.Forms.ListBox;
    lbx.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
    fm.Show();
}
```

Is

```
System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lbx = fm.Controls.Find("listBox1", true).FirstOrDefault() as System.Windows.Forms.ListBox;
```

the best way of accessing the `ListBox` and adding `Item`s to it?
Or is there any other way?

Comment: You should create a property `ListBoxData` in Form1 with type object[] and setter of the property should add values to the list. And you assign the values to that property by doing `fm.ListBoxData = new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`

Comment: Great. thanks for the hint. Could you check if my implementation looks good. I have posted as the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, since you create a new Form1 instance each time you wish to show it, and since it is a custom form, I would simply modify the form's constructor to accept the input data.

```
public Form1(object[] ListBoxData)
{
   ...
   listBox1.Items.AddRange(ListBoxData);
}
```

You can then simply just pass in the values when you click the button;

```
Form1 fm = new Form1(new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
fm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Chetan's suggestion:
Property :

```
 public object[] ListBoxData
        {
            set
            {
                listBox1.Items.AddRange(value);
            }
        }
```

Change in Button Click:

```
 Form1 fm = new Form1();
            fm.ListBoxData = new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            fm.Show();
```

Comment: In this implementation, you'll never be setting the objects in the list but rather adding them. Instead, you must use `listBox1.Items.Clear()` to empty the list and then add the new items.